# Histogram of more than two variables over an extra variable

Tags: r

I have a question. I want to create a Histogram of 4 different variables (4 Variables refer to the workload of the Student (e.g. hours spend on reading articles) over another variable (Study Program).

I tried it with the following code and got the error message, that the function "over" could not find. But I installed all required packages.

`hist(c(Workload_FSS18$Q_59953122, Workload_FSS18$Q_59953124, Workload_FSS18$Q_59953126, Workload_FSS18$Q_59953128), over(bpsy), breaks = 10)`

and I tried it in this way:

`if(Workload_FSS18$Q_59953156 == "B.Sc. Psychologie"){
  hist(c(Workload_FSS18$Q_59953122, Workload_FSS18$Q_59953124, Workload_FSS18$Q_59953126, Workload_FSS18$Q_59953128))
}`

I hope you understand what I mean and someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example, we need to now what's your data like. Use for example `dput(my_data)`, and paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you described, I think this should help.  In the future, be sure to add some dummy data so we better understand what your source data looks like.

I'm assuming your data looks something like this:

```
fake_data = data.frame(number_of_classes = c(rnorm(50, mean = 7), rnorm(50, mean = 10)),
                   hours_studying = c(rnorm(50, mean = 15), rnorm(50, mean = 10)), 
                   homework_assignments = c(rnorm(50, mean = 10), rnorm(50, mean = 7)), 
                   study_program = c(rep('biology',50),rep('math',50)))`
```

For ggplot, data is usually best represented in long format:

`fake_data_long = data.table::melt(fake_data,id.vars = c('study_program'),
                         measure.vars = c("number_of_classes",
                                          "hours_studying",
                                          "homework_assignments"))`

from here, you can either have an overlapping histogram (my preference)

`ggplot(fake_data_long, aes(x=value, fill = study_program)) + 
  geom_histogram() + 
  facet_grid(variable ~ .)`

Or a non overlapping histogram:

`ggplot(fake_data_long, aes(x=value, fill = study_program)) + 
  geom_histogram() + 
  facet_grid(variable ~ study_program)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will try this. I totally forgot to implement some dummy data. I will do this in the future.